# How define widget assets file in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii2

I try to create a widget in yii2 in this folder:

```
basic/components/input/
```

and create **"assets"** and **"view"** in that directory.
I created my widget and it works but i need add **"CSS"** an **"JS"** file to my widget.
in yii1 can use assets in widget folder but i can't do that in yii2
any body can help me?

Comment: Did you create an asset bundle for this ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

Comment: Yes. I do that but when try to see result yii throw an exception that the folder is not exist. but its exist.

Comment: i think my $sourcepath haven't valid content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my Answer.
you should create a AssetBundle in your widget dir like this:

```
/**
 * Define Assets of  inout tag widget
 */

namespace app\components\InputTag;


class InputTagAsset extends \yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = "@app/components/InputTag/assets";
    public $css = [
        'css/xx.css',
    ];
}
```

and then call your AssetBundle in your widget file in init() method like this:

```
public function init(){
        parent::init();
        InputTagAsset::register($this->view);
    }
```

and put your files in assets folder.